# Get the average number of occurrences in a list of dicts

Tags: python, date, formula, frequency

Given a list of dictionaries (a log JSON from MongoDB), where one of the values of the dict is a datetime value, I need to know the frequency it happens.

Let's say:

```
[
    {"time": "2010-11-11 03:23:59"},
    {"time": "2010-11-12 10:16:15"},
    {"time": "2010-11-12 14:51:13"},
    ...
]
```

The frequency need to be like:
`3 times in a week`
or
`1 time in an hour`
depending the frequency (if no more than one occurrence a day, return only `x times in a day`, if no more than one week, use only `x times in a week`, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could parse the strings into datetimes, find the max and the min, subtract to find a timedelta, and designate the duration based on that timedelta:

```
import datetime as dt
data=[
    {"time": "2010-11-11 03:23:59"},
    {"time": "2010-11-12 10:16:15"},
    {"time": "2010-11-12 14:51:13"},
    ]

def freq(data):
    dates=[dt.datetime.strptime(dct['time'],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for dct in data]
    date_min=min(dates)
    date_max=max(dates)
    span=date_max-date_min
    l=len(dates)
    if span<dt.timedelta(hours=1):
        duration='an hour'
    elif span<dt.timedelta(hours=24):
        duration='a day'
    elif span<dt.timedelta(days=7):
        duration='a week'
    else:
        duration='all'
    return l,duration

num,duration=freq(data)
print('{n} times in {d}'.format(n=num,d=duration))
```

yields

```
3 times in a week
```